# Is there any way to get Documents Directory synchroniously?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to load a small settings file before showing the first screen.

I'm curently using the PathProvider plugin, but all the functions in it are async.

Is there any way to find the application documents directory synchroniously and then use dart:io sync functions on it? Instead of showing a placeholder for infinite decimal of a second.

EDIT: considering the first 2 answers, probably my explaination was really bad. The answers suggested me to still use `async` code. Problem is, I need the directory before `runApp()`, and I dont want my `void main()` to be `async`, because this ruins any splash animation for sure.

And the PathProvider API is `async`, as far as I can see, only because it utilizes `MethodChannel`, which is `async`, but functions behind it in PathProvider are pretty much synchronious.

What I'm asking is - is there a way, on Android or IOS, to know ApplicationDocumentsDirectory in sync code? Maybe without using platform-specific code at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureBuilder` for the same purpose without having to worry about execution.

It will allow you to do your process in the background and allows you to show a splash screen UI until your specified process is complete and data is ready to use.

Note: Any plugin or code which needs access to the device's native method channel will be `async` by default, since access of the method channel itself is supposed to be `async`.

Comment: it is exactly what i meant under "showing a placeholder for infinite decimal of a second"